# Tesseract Package on Mac (RStudio): Installation Failure

Tags: r, tesseract

I have installed Tesseract on Mac (Big Sur)  using homebrew [formulas](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/tesseract). All dependencies are loaded.

```
brew info tesseract
==> tesseract: stable 5.3.2 (bottled), HEAD
OCR (Optical Character Recognition) engine
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract/5.3.2 (73 files, 32.7MB) *
  Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on 2023-07-16 at 21:46:16
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/tesseract.rb
License: Apache-2.0
```

However, I still cannot load the R "tesseract" package:

```
Error in library(tesseract) : there is no package called ‘tesseract’
```

When trying to install from R console, I get the following:

```
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
./tesseract_types.h:2:10: fatal error: 'leptonica/allheaders.h' file not found
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘tesseract’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/tesseract’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tesseract’ had non-zero exit status
```

When trying `brew install leptonica` in the terminal I get:

```
Warning: leptonica 1.82.0_2 is already installed and up-to-date.
```

Really can't figure it out. I have also tried to install from github using `remotes`, but I keep getting the same error:

```
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
./tesseract_types.h:2:10: fatal error: 'leptonica/allheaders.h' file not found
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating to R-4.3.1-arm64.pkg solved the issue.